# sql query to optimized execution time to filter data from table1 which are not present in table2

Tags: php, mysql

table structure...

**Scheme Master**

```
book     receipt     coupon    created
 100       700       1200      12-03-2015
 100       700       1201      12-03-2015
 100       700       1202      12-03-2015
 100       701       1203      12-03-2015
 100       701       1204      12-03-2015
 100       701       1205      12-03-2015
```

**book issue table**

```
  book_no    Alloted_city    issue_date   
  100         nagpur         15-03-2015
  100         nagpur         18-03-2015
```

Book_return table

```
 book     surveyor     used_receipt    city
 1000       raj          700           nagpur
```

**Below is my expected output..**

```
 book      printeddate    issuedate   balancereceipt  allcoupon        city
 100       12-03-2015     15-03-2015     701         1203,1204,1205    nagpur
```

**Below is my sql query .**

this works fine..but take 4 to 5 minutes to execute only 50 to 80 rows ...plz help me to  optimize below query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT BI.book_no AS book,BI.issue_date As Issuedate,BI.Alloted_city As city,SM.created AS PrintedDate,
     SM.receipt_no as AllReceipt,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SM.coupon ORDER BY coupon ASC) As Allcoupon FROM book_issue BI LEFT JOIN scheme_master SM ON SM.book_no2=BI.book_no WHERE SM.receipt_no NOT IN (select used_receipt from book_return) AND BI.Alloted_city = :cityname AND BI.book_no BETWEEN :book_no AND :book2 GROUP BY SM.receipt_no order by SM.receipt_no ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, added where clause in not in condition,

```
SELECT DISTINCT BI.book_no AS book,BI.issue_date As Issuedate,BI.Alloted_city As city,SM.created AS PrintedDate,
 SM.receipt_no as AllReceipt,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SM.coupon ORDER BY coupon ASC) As Allcoupon 
FROM book_issue BI 
LEFT JOIN scheme_master SM ON SM.book_no2=BI.book_no 
WHERE SM.receipt_no NOT IN (select used_receipt from book_return where used_receipt = SM.receipt_no) 
AND BI.Alloted_city = :cityname AND BI.book_no BETWEEN :book_no AND :book2 
GROUP BY SM.receipt_no order by SM.receipt_no ASC
```

Comment: but this also take more time to execute 5.8 sec for only 25 rows to match bcoz we filter rows from book no

Comment: for ex i enter book no between 342 and 342 ..so book 342 has only 25 records present in database...so query takes more time to execute...